# .htaccess Rewrite from Host to static site without uri

Tags: apache, .htaccess, http, mod-rewrite, https

Good Morning.
Unfortunately I didn't find any hint so far.

I want a redirect with loosing the URL.
Let's say I've the following subdomain:

> sub.test.com

and I want to redirect all traffic (`sub.test.com/` , `sub.test.com/home/`, `sub.test.com/home/start/`..) to following site:

> main.test.com/site

What I've got so far:

```
RewriteCond ${HTTP_HOST} ^sub\.test\.com
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} ^443
```

But I don't know how the `RewriteRule` must look like.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Are `sub.test.com` and `main.test.com` pointing to dame `DocumentRoot` on same host?

Comment: sub.test.com is pointing to main.test.com/site . The Problem is that sub.test.com/home/ will be redirected to main.test.com/site/home/ which results in an error.

Comment: `sub.test.com/home/` can be redirected to `main.test.com/home/` but URL will change in browser unless you enable `mod_proxy` in Apache config.

Comment: Url changes are no problem! Goal is that every access to sub.test.com/.. (to any url! e.g. sub.test.com/abc/) will be redirected to static page "main.test.com/home/". In pseudo code: if http_host = "sub\.test\.com" then redirect to "main\.test\.com\support" without url end if

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} =sub.test.com
RewriteRule ^ http://main.test.com/home/? [L,R=302]
```

Comment: RedirectMatch 301 /home/(.*) /home

This helped me.